# Regular expression named group match in any order?

Tags: c#, regex

I have the following string

```
"lu=Rg3vHJ; Expires=Tue, 15-Jan-2013 21:47:38 GMT; Path=/; Domain=.example.com; HttpOnly"
```

And I can use the following pattern to get the named groups.

```
(?<name>.+?)=(?<value>[^;]+)(?:; Expires=(?<expires>[^;]+))?(?:; Path=(?<path>[^;]+))?(?:; Domain=(?<domain>[^;]+))?(?:; (?<httponly>HttpOnly))?(?:; (?<secure>Secure))?
```

```
lu (name)
Rg3vHJ (value)
Tue, 15-Jan-2013 21:47:38 GMT (expires)
/ (path)
.example.com (domain)
HttpOnly (httponly)
 (secure)
```

However, the result will be messed up if the order of these groups change. e.g.

```
lu=Rg3vHJ; Path=/; Expires=Tue, 15-Jan-2013 21:47:38 GMT; Domain=.example.com; HttpOnly"
```

How to make the pattern works for any order of the groups?

Comment: Why not use multiple regexes instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could perhaps use:

```
^(?<name>.+?)=(?<value>[^;]+)(?:(?=.*(?:Expires=(?<expires>[^;]+))))?(?:(?=.*(?:Path=(?<path>[^;]+))))?(?:(?=.*(?:Domain=(?<domain>[^;]+))))?(?:(?=.*(?<httponly>HttpOnly)))?(?:(?=.*(?<secure>Secure)))?
```

[regex101 demo](http://regex101.com/r/gU2nB4)

It's not a pretty sight, but does the trick. Lookaheads are being used here due to the fact that they do not consume matches, and as such, can match anything anywhere ahead, without impeding in the other matches.

Using multiple regexes sure will be more maintainable.